# Specifying android emulator when real device is also connected

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I develop android apps, sometimes I need to use device and sometimes emulator, the problem is when both are connected then if I want to uninstall my app from emulator only I had to disconnect the device. There must be a way so that I can specify from which device to uninstall or install the app. I have tried adb -s option like this

```
adb -s "emulator-5554" uninstsll com.myPackage.myApp
```

But it always opens the adb help options. May be the command is not correct. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
adb -e uninstall com.myPackage.myApp
```

will serve your purpose. FYI, option -e is for emulator.

Comment: adb -s emulator-5554 uninstall com.myPackage.myApp

This is also okay. Please don't put quote around serial.

Comment: Thanks PH7, adb -e uninstall works great. I have also tried your second option, but adb -s faild even though I tried as per your advice.

Comment: you should see "adb devices" and check ur serial. Please make sure you have correct serial else you will get error.

Comment: I have checked my avd serial number by using "adb devices" but adb -s still not working  :(

Comment: In fact, there is nth wrong with your original command except mis-spelled word "uninstsll". it should be "uninstall".

I already tested.

Comment: Oh, wow, how stupid of me!! I did not notice that spelling mistake!! You are right, it works too. Thanks a lot.  :)